# Word VBA replace text appearing in selection only with uppercase

Tags: vba, ms-word

My object is simple - I want a shortcut to replace text in a selection with uppercase characters, without applying the "AllCaps" style, for reasons I won't go into here.

I have succeeded by using `Selection.Delete` and `Selection.Insert`, but that doesn't seem to preserve font styles not inherent to the paragraph style.

When I try using VBA `Selection.Find.Execute:=ReplaceAll`, it is replacing all instances in the entire document.  I am aware that this should be the behavior for `.wrap=wdFindContinue`, but I have set `.wrap=wdFindStop`.  My best guess is that because my `.text` is set as a variable that calls the `Selection` object, it loses the selection somehow when setting `.text` (although visually this is not apparent when I step through the code - selection stays highlighted), resulting in `.ReplaceAll` executing for the whole document.  If I manually enter the "find" (`.text`) string for a particular case, it executes on the selection only (even with the variable `txt` called in the .Replacement.Text field!), but obviously that won't be practical.

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReplaceWithUppercase()

Dim pasteAutoFormatSetting As Boolean
Dim txt As String
'Save current user selection of whether to adjust spacing automatically when pasting:
pasteAutoFormatSetting = Options.PasteAdjustWordSpacing

'Turn off auto spacing adjustment:
Options.PasteAdjustWordSpacing = False

txt = Selection.Range.text


With Selection.Font
        .AllCaps = False
End With

'The next two lines work but do not seem to preserve built-in font styles
'already applied to the selected text, so I wanted to instead use find/replace:

'Selection.Range.Delete
'Selection.Range.InsertAfter (UCase(txt))


    With Selection.Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .text = txt
        .Replacement.text = UCase(txt)
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With

'Return to user preference for auto apacing adjustment:
Options.PasteAdjustWordSpacing = pasteAutoFormatSetting

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PatentWookiee, I think you were on the right track initially with,

```
Selection.Range.Delete
Selection.Range.InsertAfter (UCase(txt))
```

The problem is, once you delete your selected text, anything you put in its place will assume the formatting of the first character prior to your deletion. To solve this problem you'll want to go with:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReplaceWithUppercase()
    Selection.Text = UCase(Selection.Text)
End Sub
```

Instead of replacing the actual text (and the formatting along with it) we simply replace the *case* of the selected string, thus leaving your formatting fully intact. If I've read your question right, this should fully solve your problem. If not, be sure to let me know, we'll work through it.

Comment: I like a one-line macro, thanks!  The mystery remains of whether you can execute wdReplaceAll on a selection only when the "find" text is a selection-defined string variable, but you might not ever need to use `Selection.Find` when you can just say `Selection.Text=someString`.

Comment: PatentWookiee, Not sure if this is responsive to your question, but you can certainly use: 
`Selection.Text = Replace("abcdefg", "cde", "CDE")` Which would return "abCDEfg"

Comment: Would be nice if you could use regular expressions as arguments of that Replace function, but I'm guessing not in VBA.  I have written macros that use regular expressions to find and replace text, but they're rather long winded, viz.:

Comment: `For Each para In Selection.Paragraphs

  txt = para.Range.text
  'any match?
  If re.Test(txt) Then
    'get all matches
    Set allMatches = re.Execute(txt)
    
    For Each m In allMatches
        Debug.Print m.Value
        num = m.Value + 1
        Set rng = para.Range
        rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
        rng.MoveStart wdCharacter, m.FirstIndex + offset
        rng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, m.length
        rng.text = re.Replace(rng.text, num)
        offset = offset + Len(CStr(num)) - Len(m.Value)
    Next m
  End If
Next para`

Comment: Manually moving the cursor to the beginning index of each match (accounting for any offset from previous replacements of different length), manually extending selection to the end of the match, etc.  In such cases it can be nice to use find/replace which handles that stuff for me.

Comment: In the above instance, however, I needed to build a RegEx to weed out numerals that I didn't want to increment (dimensioned quantities - negative lookahead for ft, in., e.g.) and match only those I wanted to increment (sequentially numbered part references, to be able to insert one)

Comment: Any chance you could post some example text, along with what you're trying to replace? I'm just struggling to get a complete picture of the end goal.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38512834/word-vba-replace-each-integer-i-in-a-selection-with-i-1

Answer (score 1):

Fast work using an array for selection range - and the StrConv function

```
Sub ChangeRangeToUCase()
    Const vbUpperCase = 1 ' strConv constant

    Dim arrCells    As Variant
    Dim intRow      As Integer
    Dim intCol      As Integer

    ' Assign Range to an array
    arrCells = Selection
    For intRow = LBound(arrCells, 1) To UBound(arrCells, 1)
        For intCol = LBound(arrCells, 2) To UBound(arrCells, 2)
            arrCells(intRow, intCol) = StrConv(arrCells(intRow, intCol), vbUpperCase)
        Next intCol
    Next intRow

    Selection = arrCells

End Sub
```

Comment: @Jim_Simson's answer gets the nod for simplicity, but I like seeing multiple ways to do things.

Comment: Sounds good - If you're dealing with many cells in a selection, you'll find the array method is almost instant as opposed to using selection directly

Comment: Thanks - I'll copy your macro into my library and make a note that it should execute faster than `Selection.Text = someString` for large selections.

Answer (score 0):

With help from the macro recorder we find:

```
    Sub ChangeSelectionToUCase()
        ' MsgBox Selection.Range.text
        Selection.Range.Case = wdUpperCase
        ' MsgBox Selection.Range.text
    End Sub
```

Would that be acceptable? It certainly looks a lot easier.
The OP is concerned about not using the "AllCapsStyle". But using the lines commented out, we can convince ourselves that the text in the document is really changed to uppercase, not just its visual appearance ("style").