# Word VBA - replace each integer i in a selection with i-1

Tags: regex, vba, replace, ms-word

I want to search a selection for integers and increment each by some value, such as 1.  For example, in the following text from U.S. Patent No. 6,293,874, I would want to make replacements where double brackets indicate deletions and italics indicate insertions:

"In accordance with the present invention, an amusement apparatus is provided that includes a user-operated and controlled apparatus for self-infliction of repetitive blows to the user's buttocks including a plurality of rotating arms bearing flexible extensions for self-paddling the user's buttocks B. [The drawings show an] amusement apparatus [[10]] *11* for self-paddling a user U. As illustrated in [the drawings] the self-paddling apparatus [[10]] *11* includes a display platform [[12]] *13* having a hollow interior and having a first end [[14]] *15* portion and a second end [[16]] *17* portion. The platform [[12]] *13*is constructed of materials adequate to support the weight of at least a few people standing on the platform, such as a user and an observer. In one embodiment, the platform [[12]] *13* includes at least two generally equally sized subunits that are connectable at the mid-section [[20]] *21* for folding together after any upstanding posts mounted thereon are detached. The first end [[14]] *15* portion and the second end [[16]] *17* portion includes storage compartments within the hollow platform [[12]] *13* for storage of disassembled components connectable to the platform [[12]] *13*. The first end [[14]] *15* is connected at the mid-section hinges 20 to the second end [[16]] *17* by a plurality of hinges [[22]] *23*. Once the upstanding posts and accessories are detached, disassembled and stored, the platform [[12]] *13* is foldable and securable for storage or moving to the next location for reassembly, display, and use for self-paddling."

I know how to iterate over matches in a match collection, but only for whole paragraphs, viz.

```
For Each para In Selection.Paragraphs 
txt = para.Range.text 
offset = 0
'any match? 
If re.Test(txt) Then 
'get all matches 
Set allMatches = re.Execute(txt) 
For Each m In allMatches 

    num = m.Value + 1 
    Set rng = para.Range 
    rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart 
    rng.MoveStart wdCharacter, m.FirstIndex + offset 
    rng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, m.length 
    rng.text = re.Replace(rng.text, num) 'account for added digits:
    offset = offset + Len(CStr(num)) - Len(m.Value) 

Next m 
End If 
Next para
```

Can I either (A) modify the foregoing code to search through a selection only instead of the paragraphs that it touches (in their entireties), (B) somehow use `Selection.Find.Execute:=wdReplaceAll` and be assured that it won't replace everything in the document?* (*I have noticed that if a variable is defined in relation to the `Selection` object and used in the `.text` field of `Selection.Find`, Word will replace all instances in the document, even with `.Wrap = wdFindStop`.  See [Word VBA replace text appearing in selection only with uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38030974/word-vba-replace-text-appearing-in-selection-only-with-uppercase/38034783))

Comment: "an amusement apparatus is provided that includes a user-operated and controlled apparatus for self-infliction of repetitive blows to the user's buttocks including a plurality of rotating arms bearing flexible extensions for self-paddling the user's buttocks". Really?!

Comment: You read that right.

Comment: It's a good guinea-pig example to use publicly without getting into trouble as a lawyer because (1) it was clearly never meant to be taken seriously, and (2) it lapsed a long time ago for failure to pay maintenance fees.

Comment: The idea is really that when I am drafting an application and I realize that I want to insert a reference to numbered part somewhere, while keeping introductions of new part numbers sequential in the document, I want a way to do that without tediously renumbering subsequently introduced parts one at a time.

Comment: But patent applications that I am drafting are strictly confidential.

Comment: So you're wanting to work on partial substrings of a paragraph? If so use the Left or Right string functions: http://www.homeandlearn.org/left_and_right_functions.html

Comment: I'm wanting to work on whatever string I have selected.  The selection may be a substring of a paragraph, but it may also span multiple paragraphs, in which case, assuming it is a contiguous selection, it may include only an end portion of the first paragraph touched and/or only a beginning portion of the last paragraph touched.